# Is it wrong to work 2 muscle group at once?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, strength-training

I normally work out 2 muscle groups per day,a big one and a small one for example

`back/triceps`

`chest/biceps`

`legs/shoulders`

`etc...`

But,sometimes I am in a hurry and I must hurry up the pace and I do them combined,for example I do a 15xLeg press I wait 20 seconds and I do 15xDumbell military press then I wait 1:30 minutes and again Leg press,20 seconds pause, Dumbell press,1:30 minutes pause a.s.o.

Am I stressing my body too hard when I do this?Should I train only 1 body part when I really am in a hurry?

Comment: If you are looking to isolate and overload muscles, then that's easier to do by focusing on a single muscle group.  That's more of a body building technique.  For exercise, fitness and general performance, there's probably nothing wrong with exercises that hit more than one group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the question of wrong or right, but what works for you. The conventional regime is to workout back and biceps and chest with triceps. When you are working on your chest, you are already moving your triceps, they get secondary workout. So stressing them again with back workout may not work for everyone. Ideally the rest time is 48 hours, for a set of muscles, but having said that, people are built differently when it comes to what their bodies can handle. I know some people who have been doing everything on a single day for last 5 years, and it's working for them.

So, I'd say try out various routines and see what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not wrong but is not the same thing as training a single muscle chain/section consequentially.

If you have a volume of 70 reps total ( divided in 4 exercises ) for, let's say chest, you want to perform all of those ( if you're going with 70%-80% intensity ) with at max 60 to 90 seconds of pause between sets.

If you do like you said your metabolic stimuli will be different while mechanically its the same thing. It's not "bad" but for hypetrophy is better going consequentially.

Comment: So in other words I wont grow as fast as doing them single even tho those 2 muscle group have nothing to do one with the other?

Comment: No one can know that. Hypertrophy is a consequence, not a result. It will have a different result. Training like you want to train it's not the best possible stimulus you can provide for hypetrophy, but triggers some kind of endurance features ( crossfit like ).

Answer (score 0):

With the scenario you've given, I say it's alright. Leg press works the lower part of your body, your quads for the most part whereas military press works out your shoulders and a little bit of triceps. And it's okay since your workout plan involves you to target legs and shoulder for the day.

Resting completely without doing military press after your leg press lets you recuperate a bit more for the next set of leg press. So, you'd be able to do a little bit more on your leg press if you just rested completely. So, you're basically trading off your gain in both leg press and military press for the amount of time saved. But, for me, that's fine